# When I “.$ajax get" a large JSON file(with pointclouds, about 120,000 lines), there will be a big delay. How to solve it?

Tags: html, ajax, web, three.js, point-clouds

I want to display pointclouds in real time on web page. Each JSON of pointclouds is about 3M, but the step of ".$ajax get" will be stuck for nearly 20 seconds in each loop. I can't display pointclouds smoothly. How to solve this?
I used three.js for show pointcloud, and Mongoose for server.

client:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>three.js pointcloud viewer</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- 全局js -->
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js?v=2.1.4"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js?v=3.3.6"></script> 

        <!-- Import maps polyfill -->
        <!-- Remove this when import maps will be widely supported -->
        <script async src="https://unpkg.com/es-module-shims@1.6.3/dist/es-module-shims.js"></script>

        <script type="importmap">
            {
                "imports": {
                    "three": "./js/three.js-dev/build/three.module.js",
                    "three/addons/": "./js/three.js-dev/examples/jsm/"
                }
            }
        </script>

        <script type="module">

            import * as THREE from 'three';

            import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';
            import { GUI } from 'three/addons/libs/lil-gui.module.min.js';

            let camera, scene, renderer;
            var geometry;  // Object of type THREE.Geometry containing the visible points.
            var material;  // Object of type THREE.PointCloudMaterial for point color and size.
            var pointCloud;  // The object that represents the visible cloud of points.
            var points;  // An array of Vector3, containing all possible points

            init();
            render();

            function init() {

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 30, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 40 );
                camera.position.set( 0, 0, -5 );
                camera.lookAt(0, -80, 0);
                camera.up.set(0, -1, 0);

                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                scene.add( camera );

                const controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
                controls.addEventListener( 'change', render ); // use if there is no animation loop
                controls.minDistance = 0.5;
                controls.maxDistance = 10;

                geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
                material = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
                        color: "white",
                        size: 1,
                        sizeAttenuation: false
                    });

                getLoc();

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize );

            }
            
            function getLoc()
            {
                $.ajax
                ({
                    type: "GET",
                    url:'/data/get_showmap',
                    cache:false,
                    success:function(data, status)
                    {
                        var jdata = JSON.parse(data);
                        
                        const points = new Array();
                        for(var i = 0; i < 3 * jdata.size; i++)
                        {
                            if (i%3 == 2){
                                var x = -jdata.vertex[i-2]*10;
                                var y = -jdata.vertex[i-1]*10;
                                var z = jdata.vertex[i]*10;
                                points.push(new THREE.Vector3(x,y,z));
                            }
                        }
                        geometry.setFromPoints(points);
                        pointCloud = new THREE.Points(geometry,material);

                        clearScene();
                        scene.add(pointCloud);

                        renderer.render( scene, camera );

                        const gui = new GUI();
                        gui.add( pointCloud.material, 'size', 0.1, 1 ).onChange( render );
                        gui.addColor( pointCloud.material, 'color' ).onChange( render );
                        gui.open();

                        render();
                        setTimeout(getLoc(), 1000);
                    }
                });
            }

            function onWindowResize() {

                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

                render();

            }

            function clearScene(){
                for(var i = 0; i < scene.children.length; i++)
                {
                    if (scene.children[i].type == "Points")
                    {
                        deleteGroup(scene.children[i]);
                        scene.remove(scene.children[1]);
                    }
                }
            }

            function deleteGroup(group) {
                if (!group) return;
                group.traverse(function (item) {
                    item.geometry.dispose();
                    item.material.dispose();
                });
            }

            function render() {
                renderer.render( scene, camera );
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

server:

```cpp
void CWirelessMonitor::threadFn()
{
    struct mg_mgr mgr;
    struct mg_connection *nc;
    mg_mgr_init(&mgr, NULL);
    printf("Starting web server on port %s\n", s_http_port);
    nc = mg_bind(&mgr, s_http_port, ev_handler);
    if (nc == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to create listener\n");
        return;
    }
    // Set up HTTP server parameters
    mg_set_protocol_http_websocket(nc);
    s_http_server_opts.document_root = "/home/ljl/WorkSpace/UI/UI_Camera/web_root";
    s_http_server_opts.enable_directory_listing = "yes";
    while (!m_quitMutex.try_lock_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10))) {        
        mg_mgr_poll(&mgr, 1000);
    }
}

static void ev_handler(struct mg_connection *nc, int ev, void *ev_data)
{
    struct http_message *hm = (struct http_message *) ev_data;
    switch (ev)
    {
    case MG_EV_HTTP_REQUEST:
        if (mg_vcmp(&hm->uri, "/data/get_showmap") == 0)
        {
            if (is_equal(&hm->method, &s_get_method))
                handle_cam_get(nc, hm);
            else
            {
                mg_printf(nc, "%s",
                          "HTTP/1.0 501 Not Implemented\r\n"
                          "Content-Length: 0\r\n\r\n");
            }
        }
        else
            mg_serve_http(nc, hm, s_http_server_opts); /* Serve static content */
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

static void handle_cam_get(struct mg_connection *nc, struct http_message *hm)
{
    (void)hm;
    /* Send headers */
    mg_printf(nc, "%s", "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nTransfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n\r\n");

    Json::Value root;
    Json::Reader reader;
    start = std::clock();
    std::ifstream camFile("/home/ljl/WorkSpace/UI/UI_Camera/web_root/models/pcd/binary/bun.json");
    if(!camFile.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "Error opening file\n" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    reader.parse(camFile, root);
    auto json = root.toStyledString();  // auto json = MonitorDataConfig::getData();

    mg_send_http_chunk(nc, json.c_str(), json.size());
    mg_send_http_chunk(nc, "", 0); /* Send empty chunk, the end of response */
}
```

JSON is like:

```json
{
    "descrition" : "vertex, each is a 3 element vector",
    "name" : "aa",
    "size" : 40256,
    "vertex" : 
    [
        -0.063249997794628143,
        0.035979300737380981,
        0.04208730161190033,
                ...
        ]
}
```

When the JSON is smaller, it will show faster.
Want to show a realtime pointclouds on web, Which part do I need to change?

Comment: First step of solving any performance is identifying where your bottleneck is.

Comment: Why do you do it every second? `setInterval(getLoc,1000);`. Did you mean to use `setTimeout`? Get in the habit of debugging your code, start with `console.log`, and in this case the Chrome performance tab can help you. Also generating geometry is expensive and Javascript is slow, and point cloud data is typically large, without some serious optimization you might not get good performance.

Comment: .js is always changing, so I want to refresh geometry all the time, but I didn't realize the delay at the beginning. Thank you for your suggestion, I haven't been exposed to web programming before. Now, I may know where to start.